# Spatial, strangle lines when using Map View

Tags: sql, oracle, spatial

I'm attempting to make my first spatial map using SQL developer and map view. 
And this polygon with hole has me stuck:
[screenshot!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l56qz.jpg)

Here's the insert code I used:

```
insert into FIELDS values(
    3, MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, NULL, NULL, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,1, 23,2003,1),
    MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(47,56, 75,56, 75,60, 60,60, 60,75, 75,75, 75,77, 50,77, 
    50,60, 47,60, 47,56, 54,60, 54,75, 58,75, 58,60, 54,60)), 'pathway');
```

And my metadata for the table:

```
insert into user_sdo_geom_metadata(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DIMINFO, SRID)
  values('FIELDS', 'FIELD', mdsys.sdo_dim_array(mdsys.sdo_dim_element('X', 0, 110, 1),
  mdsys.sdo_dim_element('Y', 0, 110, 1)), null);
```

Couldn't find anything on Google, so any idea what might the triangle-like lines in the bottom left corner?

EDIT:
Create code of the table... in case that turns out useful:

```
create table FIELDS(
  FIELD_ID number(10) constraint pk_FIELDS primary key,
  FIELD mdsys.sdo_geometry,
  FIELD_NAME varchar2(60)
);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this turned out to be no more than a weird glitch. If you ever encounter this problem: rollback, restart the system and try again. At least for me that fixed it.